# Someone can help me in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

### I have these exercises

Define a function to count the total negative numbers in a list.   ##

I've tried this

```
 negative :: [Int] -> Int
 negative list = [ x | x <- list, if list<0 then x=1 else x=0]
```

And also

3. Define the function

   ```
      choose :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] 

      that chooses all occurrences of an integer n in a list. For example 

       chooses 1 [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1] results in [1, 1, 1] choosing 1 [2, 3, 4, 6] results []
   ```

I've tried this

```
      choose :: Int->[Int]->[Int]
      choose xs ys s [rep-rep<-xs,z<-ys,rep-z]
```

Or

```
      rep ::Int->[Int]->[Int]
      rep _ [][]
      rep a (b:bs)-a-b-a:rep a []
      |otherwise-rep a (bs)

       rp :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
       rp [] (ys)[]
       rp (x:xs) (ys)-k++rp (xs) (ys)
       where k'rep x (ys)
```

My teacher never explained this to us that's why I have these doubts, I'm new to haskell

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
negative :: [Int] -> Int
negative list = [ x | x <- list, if list<0 then x=1 else x=0]
```

Makes no sense for several reasons:

1. the result type is an `Int`, so by using list comprehension as outer expression, you are generating a list;
2. `x` is an element of the list `x <- list`, `if list < 0 then … else …` makes no sense since `list` is a list, and can not be compared with a single element; and
3. variables can not be assigned a new value. Variables are defined once, here by `x <- list`. You can make a more locally scoped variable with the same name, but that is not a good idea here.

You can just use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) here to filter the list and only retain the elements less than `0` and then calculate the [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length):

```
negative :: [Int] -> Int
negative list = length (filter (< 0) list)
```

we can make these point-free, and let this work with any `Num` type:

```
negative :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
negative = length . filter (< 0)
```

Comment: Hoo thanks, is that I have never seen those reserved words in haskell and since we are in lists I thought that it should be as I put it.
I will try as you say

Comment: @Bryan: those are *not* reserved words, these are just functions defined in the `Prelude`. The `<` operator is defined in the `Prelude` as well.